# Trying to convert time stored in a string, when it contains a colon, to an int value.

Tags: android, type-conversion

When a user enters a time via a spinner and that time is 17:00 then I want to return an error Toast, now as I have declared my beginTime as a String within my spinner I need to convert this back to an Int in order to check if that value is equal to 17:00

```
 public void checkBeginTime()

 String begingTime = beginTimespinner.getText().toString();

   if (beginTime == 17:00)
   {
   Toast.etc
   }

   else 

   {
   add beginTime;
   }
```

if i try to do this then it wont work beacuse of the `:`, any ideas?

Comment: What is "Module"? And what are you trying to do? if (s == 17:00) isn't valid java/android code.

Comment: how do you expect ":" to be parsed as a number...? you should really work on your programming skills before posting this kind of questions.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I tend to agree--this is poorly worded, even after an edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
   your_str = your_str.replace(":", ""); 

   your_int = Intger.parseInt(your_str);
```

You end up with a unique integer.

Comment: @goldilocks, yep, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming beginTime is a String in the first place, then you **never** compare Strings with ==.
You must use the .equals() method. (Google for why not).

In Java you do it like this:

```
private void testVal(String beginTime) {
        String testVal = "17:00";
        if (testVal.equals(beginTime)){
            System.out.println("Matched " + beginTime);
            // Or whatever you want in Android, such as Toast
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No match with " + beginTime);
            // Or whatever you want in Android, such as Toast
        }

    }
```

An you would invoke that method with:

```
String beginTime = "17:00"; // or in your case beginTimespinner.getText().toString();
test.testVal(beginTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int MyInt=Integer.parseInt("17.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely hard to understand what you're asking. In the future, take some time before posting to collect your thoughts.

I'll take a stab though.

> "17:00"

is a string you've said. Usually, when talking about string -> int conversions, the end goal is clear, i.e it's easily understood what you want like

> "15" -> 15; "-2" -> -2 // etc

The colon is tricky for this reason, do you want 17 or 1700?  Very different obviously. You can control this by string manipulation though. Say you wanted 1700, you could do:

```
String str = "17:00";
int StrAsInt = Integer.ParseInt(str.replace(":",""));
```

Or for 17, substring index 0 to the index of the colon. The point is, you need to do some leg work yourself to convert something like that to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) to get the user to input the time, have you considered using either [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) or [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) instead?

The following bits of code have been grabbed from the Time Picker tutorial.  I've only pasted the relevant methods to illustrate my point, but the full tutorial can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html):

```
public class HelloTimePickerActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mTimeDisplay;
private Button mPickTime;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // capture our View elements
    mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
    mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

  // snip...
}

// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mHour = hourOfDay;
        mMinute = minute;
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the call back `onTimeSet()` is passed the hours and minutes as `int` values, easy for you to check.